# Difference between step 3 and step 5 of BGP route selection process?

Tags: bgp

Step 3: Locally injected routes (Locally injected is better than iBGP/ eBGP learned)

Step 5: Origin   Prefer I over E. Prefer E over ?

I went through lot of articles on the internet but not able to distinguish between two. I would appreciate some examples are given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Locally injected means the route was learned on that router, as opposed to learned from a peer.

Internal origin means the route came from an IGP. External means BGP, undetermined is anything else, like a redistributed route.

Comment: Is there a particular scenario where there is a tie in step 3 and is resolved in step 5?

Comment: Router A learns the same prefix from router B and C.  The path length is the same, as is local pref. Router B sourced the route from a network statement in its bgp config, while router C had it redistributed into bgp from a static route.  In this case, B is preferred.